# Mandatory Column Popup in Modern SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, content-type, site-column, modern-experience

In an Office 365 Modern Experience SharePoint site, I'm unable to find a way to force a prompt for mandatory values attached to the List Content Type.

Instead of providing a prompt for the values as with SP2013 on-prem the document just gets uploaded (or created, have tested both) and the field gains the 'Required Values' shading. The user is never actually prompted for the values.

Have tried some combinations of settings based on [this article](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3045118/how-to-ensure-that-users-are-prompted-for-document-metadata-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-2016.html) but the fix the author suggests (published 2016) doesn't seem to work anymore.

Tests were carried out with a fresh Document Library, with a Simple Text field and a Managed Metadata field both set to mandatory:

```
test 1 - mandatory fields only
no prompt given to complete required values

test 2 - mandatory field plus mandatory check out for editing
no prompt given to complete required values

test 3 - mandatory fields, no mandatory check out, CT management enabled
no prompt given to complete required values

test 4 - mandatory fields, CT management plus mandatory checkout
no prompt given to complete required values

test 5 - as test 4 but with Simple Text field only, no MMS
no prompt given to complete required values
```

Have also tried turning on 'Launch forms in a dialog' which makes no difference. Results are the same for either the default Document CT or one added from the CT Hub. Not tested an entirely fresh CT created in the Hub (cannot create one at site level) yet but don't see much value in doing so.

Does anyone have a way to prompt users for the field values while still retaining Modern Experience? Am I missing something obvious, perhaps a setting at the Content Type Hub level?